# Ruby command line using "-e" switch, problem printing to stdout

Tags: ruby

I want to take a string of characters, parse out only the numbers, and then print that string of numbers to stdout.  It has to be done with one line using the `ruby -e` switch on the command line.  It must be one line because I'm using this as part of a applescript with the `do shell script` command.

Here's the code I came up with:

`ruby -e '%{303-123-4567}.to_s.chars.to_a {|char| print char if char =~ /\d/}'`

I realize print is being called for each digit.  It's Friday and my brain is fried.  :-)  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186):

```
$ ruby -e 'print %{303-123-4567}.gsub(/[^\d]/, "")'
3031234567
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the block to the `to_a` method, that don't do any thing with a block. You can easly do:

```
%{303-123-4567}.each_char {|ch| print ch if ch =~ /\d/}
```

You can use `scan` too:

```
%{303-123-4567}.scan(/\d/) {|num| print num}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need a .map in there?

```
ruby -e '%{303-123-4567}.to_s.chars.to_a.map {|char| print char if char =~ /\d/}'
```

Seems to do what you want.

(Disclaimer: I'm not a Ruby programmer so may have missed the point here!)